# Convert text in one line and write in a file (Python)

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to write some text in a file. These are email message and thus spanned over multiple line. What I want is that every message goes on a single line.
I'm using following code snippet:

```
fh = open("hello.txt", "w") 
fh.write(e.rstrip('\n')) 

fh.close()
```

Comment: What is `e`? Is that the content of the email?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `emails` is a list of strings corresponding to your emails, you can do that :

```
emails = ["first email \n containing words and letters \n over several lines",
             "Second email \n same thing \n many words \n many lines"]
with open("hello.txt", "w") as fh: 
    for email in emails:
        #we remove all newlines then add one at the end
        fh.write(email.replace("\n"," ")+"\n")
```